# Asymptotic expansion of an integral with quadratic exponent

Tags: integration, limits

I want to expand the following integral as $N\to\infty$
$$I(N,\alpha,\beta)= \int_0^1 dx\, \exp\left(-N(\alpha x+\beta x^2 \right))$$
Would be great to do this in general, but only for $\alpha,\beta>0$ also helpful.

For positive $\alpha,\beta$ I expect the leading asymptotic to be independent of $\alpha$, but I'm not sure how to show it. More generally, this looks like a very basic problem, but I don't know how to approach it. Any method which is generalizable would be great.

Comment: Look up Laplace's method. There's a Wiki page

Comment: Another way would be to substitute $x=y/N$, then expand $e^{-\beta y^2/N}$ as a Taylor series and integrate term by term. You should get an asymptotic series that way

Comment: It is $$\alpha\sqrt{\beta}>0$$

Comment: The definite integral can be expressed in terms of the error function.

Comment: By the way, there is no need for three independent parameters. Maybe consider $M:=N\alpha$ and $\rho:=\beta/\alpha$.

Comment: @YuriyS Isn't Laplace's method only working when the function has an extremum on the interval?

Comment: @WeatherReport, you are right. In any case, series expansion is a more fruitful method

Comment: Tha AsymptoticIntegrate command of Mathematica 12.0 answers $$ -\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{\frac{\alpha ^2}{\beta }} e^{\frac{\alpha ^2 N}{4 \beta }}}{2 \alpha  \sqrt{N}}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{\frac{(\alpha +2 \beta )^2}{\beta }} e^{\frac{\alpha ^2 N}{4 \beta }}}{2 \sqrt{N} (\alpha +2 \beta )}-\frac{e^{N (-\alpha -\beta )}}{N (\alpha +2 \beta )}+\frac{1}{\alpha  N}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$I(N,\alpha,\beta)=\sqrt\pi\frac{e^{N\alpha^2/4\beta}}{2\sqrt{N\beta}}\left(\text{erf}\left(\sqrt N\frac{\alpha+2\beta}{2\sqrt\beta}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\sqrt N\frac{\alpha}{2\sqrt\beta}\right)\right).$$

Note that the limit can be evaluated with L'Hospital, which removes the error function.

Comment: If I had an $x^4$ term in the exponent, what would I do? Is there a general approach?

Comment: @WeatherReport: maybe with L'Hospital.